# Upper bound on expectation of truncated random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with expectation $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Let $Y$ be the truncation of $X$ below its mean value:
$$
Y =max\{\mu,X\}
$$
Is there an upper bound on $E[Y]$ in terms of $\mu,\sigma$?

For example, if $X \sim U\{\mu-\sigma,\mu+\sigma\}$ then $E[Y] = \mu + \frac{\sigma}{2}$. If $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $E[Y] = \mu + \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you shoud use this expression of the maximum :
$$\max(x,y) = \frac{|x-y| + x + y}{2}.$$

Then you would get
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mu + \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X - \mu|]}{2}.$$

By Hölder's inequality, you get the bound
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] \leq \mu + \frac{\sigma}{2}.$$